# SQL Select Case Statement With Where Condition In Nested Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to insert a `SELECT CASE` statement to add a column `"acct_profile_ext.acct_pay_terms"`, to a nested condition table. So the only table that can link with this table is `"acct_profile"`, which is `"acct_profile.acct_id = acct_profile_ext.acct_id"`. Problem is this table `"acct_profile"` is heavily linked to other table as well, so I need to add this column without effect the result of other table.

So now I've insert the statement at the column part, but I'm not sure how to add the column with `WHERE` condition inside the `SELECT CASE` statement.

```
(SELECT CASE acct_profile_ext.acct_pay_terms
WHEN 'CASH' THEN
(SELECT acct_profile_ext.acct_pay_terms FROM acct_profile_ext, acct_profile
WHERE acct_profile.acct_id = acct_profile_ext.acct_id)
WHEN 'CHEQUE' THEN
(SELECT acct_profile_ext.acct_pay_terms FROM acct_profile_ext, acct_profile
WHERE acct_profile.acct_id = acct_profile_ext.acct_id)
ELSE NULL
END
FROM acct_profile_ext)
```

Please advise and help. Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired result will help greatly, as your question is unclear. 1.What do you mean by "without effect the result of other table"? Insert ONLY affects the tablename that follows the "insert" word, regardless of joins. 2. Your subqueries are the same in CASH and CHEQUE case 3. It is probably better to do some joins instead of subqueries 4. Many will advise towards moving to inner join syntax rather than the old "tablename1,tablename2" syntax.

Comment: Why are you using these sub-selects and not just regular `join`s?

Comment: @iamdave clearly the OP thinks it's still 1989. :)

Comment: Also MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products. Please only tag the relevant RDBMS. Considering you tagged SQL Server 2008, I assume that's what you are using, not MySQL.

Comment: Time to start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: But this needs a complete overhaul to be honest. The case expression is used to return a scalar value, you don't have that here. We need a lot more detail to be able to help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/